# Updating knockout model when using foreach binding with array of objects

Tags: knockout.js

I am following the example [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to create a custom binding.  The property to be updated is obtained like this in the documentation:

```
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value(false);
```

In my code, a table is bound to an array of objects using knockout's `foreach` binding.

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: sites, as: 'site'}">
    <td class="siteid" data-bind="text: site.siteid"></td>
    <td class="expirydate" data-bind="datepicker: site.expirydate"></td>
          et cetera
```

The table seems to be correctly populated with data. The values are all in the right place.

The objects in the array have a few string properties and a couple of dates, so several of the table cells have jQuery UI datepickers attached to them.  Here's the custom datepicker binding code I'm using, which I found here on SO, though I don't have the reference handy (it was from a response by Mr Niemeyer, as I recall).

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            //initialize datepicker with some optional options
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {},
                $el = $(element);

            $el.datepicker(options);

            //handle the field changing
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                var newVal = $el.datepicker("getDate")
                observable(newVal);
               // a breakpoint is set at this location
            });
          .
          .
          . <snip>
```

The code crashes on `observable(newVal);`

However, if I change

```
var observable = valueAccessor();
```

to

```
 var observable = valueAccessor;
```

then the code runs without error. But when I examine the value in `observable` afterwards, at the breakpoint location, it does not contain the date value in  `newVal`; rather it contains the *original* date value.

And if instead of `observable(newVal)` I try this instead:

```
     allBindingsAccessor().value(newVal);
```

I get an error: " Object doesn't support property or method 'value'".

Comment: have you tried `ko.unwrap` and later pass it .

Comment: I am not clear about what you are suggesting with `later pass it`. I want to update the model with the current date value from the datepicker. The user has made an edit to the row. Not sure how to get the date into the model, when using the custom binding.

Comment: yes it wont update please check the answer posted . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The individual properties of the objects in my array of objects were not observables.

So, when I add a new site object to my Sites array, I needed to be doing this:

```
              var Site = function(siteid, sitename, expirydate) {
                  this.siteid=siteid;
                  this.sitename = ko.observable(sitename);
                  this.expirydate = ko.observable(expirydate);

              }


              function SitesViewModel(){

                  var self=this;
                  self.sites = ko.observableArray([]);

                  self.sites.push( new Site ( ......) );

               }
```

so that  `valueAccessor()` returns an observable, not simply an integer or string or date object, as the case may be.

Answer (score 0):

well yes it wont update the model sadly where Reasons Unknown .

But i made things work for me in different approach .

**With CSHTML syntax :**

```
<input type="text"  data-bind="value:$data.CompletionDate,datePicker:true " />
```

**Points i noticed :**
-In data-bind if you remove `value` and  try keeping some custom binding like below model wont get update

```
<input type="text"  data-bind="formatdate:$data.CompletionDate,datePicker:true " />
enter code here
```

-instead i tried using old fashioned way keeping `value` intact and added `Datepicker:true` whihc serves my purspose of binding and date selection .

**My Datepicker binding handler**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datePicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); //ko.unwrap based on version you use 

            if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                $(element).datepicker(value);
            }
            else {
                $(element).datepicker(/* your default options here */);
            }
        }
}
```

Well above approach may or maynot solve your issue but its definitely a cheery in mouth .